# Hashing trick vizualisation

Tags: machine-learning, categorical-data, data-visualization, dimensionality-reduction, feature-engineering

I have a dataset with 4 classes with some numerical and categorical data.

I was interested in using the [hashing trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_hashing) so I use the Feature Hasher available in [scikit learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.FeatureHasher.html).

I wanted to have a vizualisation of the data to see if there were any separation or groups and was wondering if it is correct to do a PCA after a hashing trick. 
I ask this since after a hashing trick, we have already transfrom the data.

Is there any other vizualisation that can be done after a hashing trick ?